# How to make .less files to have .css syntax highlight in Vim?

Tags: css, less

I've been using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and I find it very useful

I would like to have CSS syntax highlight in Vim with all .less files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

http://leafo.net/lessphp/vim/

Check the INSTALL file for instructions.

Comment: Would be useful if you provided the actual information in the answer and not only a link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: You should quote the explanation, paraphrase it, or add your own explanation rather than post a link to it. If the link one day becomes broken, your answer is no longer helpful. In fact the link seems to be broken as I write this comment.

Answer (score 20):

There are also a couple of github repos:

- https://github.com/groenewege/vim-less
- https://github.com/lunaru/vim-less

Comment: groenewege/vim-less is working better for me than lunaru's and lessphp's.

Comment: as jo liss says, groenewege is what you want. it goes nicely with two other plugins. if you have pathogen installed, you can just run these three git commands in your `~/.vim/bundle` directory:  `git clone https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color.git` `git clone https://github.com/groenewege/vim-less`
`git clone https://github.com/hail2u/vim-css3-syntax`

Answer (score 13):

If you only want to use Vim's syntax highlighting, then you can set the filetype of every LESS file to be a CSS file.

To do this, you can add `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.less set filetype=css` to your `.vimrc` file.

`au` stands for `autocommand`, so the above line reads "on events `BufNewFile` or `BufRead`, if the file has a `less` extension, then set the `filetype` option to `css`".

Keep in mind that this is not the recommended way. According to the [Vim tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_vimrc_file_clean):

> If there is a new file extension that you want Vim to recognize, don't muck about with augroup in your .vimrc, put the settings in the right place. See [:help ftdetect](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/help?tag=ftdetect)

Comment: The other reason not to do this is that there are aspects of less that vim's css syntax highlighting (correctly) considers wrong - for example nested curly braces

Answer (score 4):

Paste this line into your .vimrc:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.less setfiletype css
```

`au` is a shorthand for `autocmd`. So this reads as "when I read or open a new file that ends in .less, automatically set the filetype as CSS".